# How to implement an interface which inherits an class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, oop

I need to implement some count of interfaces (IUserAccess for example).

All of these interfaces inherit the IBase interface which contains an Execute method, so I want to implement IBase just one time.

Like this:

```
class IBase{
  Execute(data: any): void{
    console.log('Execute');
  };

interface IUserAccess extends IBase {
  CheckPassword(username: string, password: string): boolean;
}

class UserAccess implements IUserAccess{
  CheckPassword(username: string, password: string): boolean {
    console.log('CheckPassword');
    Execute({...});
    ...
  }

}
```

But IDE says:

```
>Class 'UserAccess' incorrectly implements interface 'IUserAccess'.  
Property 'Execute' is missing in type 'UserAccess' but required in type 'IUserAccess'.
```

How I can resolve my issue?

Comment: It seems when you extend class with interface, you loose method implementations, so you will have to implement Execute in UserAccess class.

Comment: But implement of Execute in UserAccess class is bad solution for me because I need to implement more than 20 interfaces each of them have the same Execute method and I dont want to make a copypast of Execute body for each interface implementation

Comment: I guess you can skip interface and just extend IBase like `class UserAccess extends IBase` and access Execute like `this.Execute({...})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution

```
class IBase{
  Execute(data: any): void{
    console.log('Execute');
  };
}

interface IUserAccess {
  CheckPassword(username: string, password: string): boolean;
}

class UserAccess extends IBase implements IUserAccess {
  CheckPassword(username: string, password: string) {
    console.log('CheckPassword');
    this.Execute({...});
    ...
    return true;
  }
}
```